# What are the advantages/disadvantages of neural net packages in R?

Tags: r, neural-network

I've seen that there are four neural net packages in R:

- `neural`
- `neuralnet`
- `nnet`
- `RSNNS`
- `H2O`

What are the advantages/disadvantages of those compared with each other?

As I found out `NeuralNetTools` only provides additional tools.

Comment: I would also add h2o's deeplearning to the list. It's one of the most powerful implementations of NNets accessible from R. And I think it scales up really well.

Comment: I primarily use h2o now, built in parallel processing and ram allocation is very nice.

Answer (score 3):

take a look at these blogs- [R for Deep Learning - 1](http://www.parallelr.com/r-deep-neural-network-from-scratch/) and [R for Deep Learning - 2](http://www.parallelr.com/r-dnn-parallel-acceleration/).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Not the most in-depth analysis of the packages themselves, but +1 for some information at least :-). I got the a little the impression the take away is "everything sucks", but maybe I am over-critical.

Comment: Glad, it could help a lil, atleast. But no worries will try to find something more specific and will update you on that. Cheers! :).